# Yahoo answers links not working in Firefox

Tags: firefox, internet-explorer

For some reason when Yahoo Answers links appear in google search results, I am unable to click these links in Firefox, it just brings me to a blank page. In IE this works fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Consider this to be an act of mercy...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The same thing happened to me!  And it was all Yahoo sites, not just Answers.  I FINALLY solved my problem today.

Do you have the Firefox add-on Disconnect enabled? If so, do the following:

- Firefox Tools -> Add-ons
- Remove Disconnect
- Restart Firefox
- Reinstall Disconnect (I was running version 1.0.0 I believe, but reinstalling gave me version 0.0.0)
- Restart Firefox
- Try Googling a Yahoo answers question and open the link

Hopefully it'll work!  I was having the same problem and once I disabled Disconnect, I realized that was the issue.  But for internet security, I reinstalled it and luckily the Yahoo sites still worked.