# (Solved) Firefox links not working, in some pages (appear dead, won't load)

Tags: firefox, links

For the last couple of years links in a certain legal search page stopped working. They were not clickable.

This is related to [Yahoo answers links not working in Firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/393381/yahoo-answers-links-not-working-in-firefox) but I have never used the add-on referred to there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is *not* caused by any add-on, acceleration etc so save your time.  It is caused by Firefox's zoom and sidebar.

As at FF74 (and many previous versions):

-If the sidebar is **open**, links in that particular page act dead at 80% and 67%.

-If the sidebar is **closed**, links act dead at 90% and 100%.

(This may also depend on window size- I use a portrait shape window. Not checked.)

[image]